# Typescript specific string value in the array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is Tuple in typescript to achieve this to check the value sequence in the array? I'd like to check all the value inside the array must follow the sequence.

`index: 0 is "hello"`, `index: 1 is "world"` and `index: 2 is "morning"`

As example:

```
const correctSequence = ['hello', 'world', 'morning']
const inCorrectSequence = ['world', 'hello', 'morning']

const Component = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Child names={correctSequence} />
            <Child names={inCorrectSequence} />
        </>
    )
}

type Names = 'hello' | 'world' | 'morning'

interface ChildProps {
    names: Names[]; // ---> not complaint in incorrect array order
}

const Child = ({names}: ChildProps) => {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe( | ) operator works as a or operator in typescript so what is happening in your `ChildProps` is that the typescript understands that the `names` field should be an array and the values of that array should be either 'hello', 'world' or 'morning. The sequence won't matter.

If you want to force the sequence then directly declare the values in the type as below.

```
type Names = ["hello", "world", "morning"]

interface ChildProps = {
   names: Names
}
```

This will force the Child component to only accept `["hello", "world", "morning"]` values with the specified sequence.